# A bounded subset in $\mathbb R^2$ which is "nowhere convex"?

Tags: real-analysis, reference-request, convex-analysis

Let $F : \mathbb S^1 \to \mathbb R^2$ represents a simple closed curve $C$ in $\mathbb R^2$. The Jordan curve theorem says that the curves bounds a interior domain $\Omega$ and $\partial \Omega= C$. Do we always have two points $a, b\in C$ such that the line segment joining $a$ and $b$ lies completely in $\Omega$? What's more, can we have

"For all $\epsilon>0$, there is two points $a ,b\in C$ such that $|a- b| < \epsilon$ and the line segment joining $a$ and $b$ lies completely in $\Omega$".

It seems that it is related to how the $C$ oscillate. If $C$ is some kinds of fractal curves, it might happens that $C$ is nowhere convex. What if we assume that $F$ is of bounded variation?

This question is related to the following [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/726333/uniqueness-of-curve-of-minimal-length-in-a-closed-x-subset-mathbb-r2):

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no "nowhere convex" subset, and bounded variation is not needed.

**Claim.** *Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb R^n$ be a bounded open set. Then for every $\epsilon>0$ there exist two points $a,b\in \partial \Omega $ such that $|a-b|<\epsilon$ and $\{(1-t)a+tb:0<t<1\}\subset \Omega $.*

**Proof.** Let $r = \sup \{|x| : x\in {\Omega}\}$. For a small $\epsilon>0$, pick a point $p\in \Omega$ with $|p|>r-\epsilon$. Let $L$ be a line through $p$ in a direction orthogonal to the line segment $[0,p]$. The intersection $L\cap \Omega$ is an open subset of $L$. Since $\Omega\subset B_r = \{x: |x|< r\}$,  the Pythagorean theorem implies $$ \operatorname{diam}(L\cap \Omega) \le \operatorname{diam}(L\cap B_r) = 2 \sqrt{r^2 - (r-\epsilon )^2} $$
which  can be made arbitrarily small. Any connected component of $L\cap \Omega$ is a line segment contained in $\Omega$ and with endpoints   $a,b\in \partial \Omega$. $\quad \Box$